# Force virtualenv pip to be used

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

Running Ubuntu 16.10 with Python 2.7.12+ (default one) and virtualenv 15.0.3 (`sudo -H pip install virtualenv`). What am I doing wrong?

```bash
$ virtualenv a && . "$_"/bin/activate && pip --version
New python executable in /tmp/a/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
pip 9.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ /tmp/a/bin/pip --version
pip 9.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ /tmp/a/bin/python -c 'from pip import __file__; print __file__'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: Are you sure that activation (sourcing) worked 100%? Print environment variables and check that's indeed the case. Which shell are you using (I assume BASH)? Could it be that you are denied setting (some) env variables?

Comment: Just regular Bash 4.3.46(1)-release in GNOME Terminal. When I `activate` the virtualenv this appears in my `env` output: `VIRTUAL_ENV=/tmp/a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling `$venv/bin/python $venv/lib/site-packages/pip/__main__.py`? That should work.

To find out why the wrong pip is being called, you should look at:

- `$PATH`, what order is it, `which pip` and `which python` will also help
- `sys.path`, what order is it, does `/usr/local/lib/` appear before the venv
- `$PYTHONPATH`, which affects `sys.path`
- possible symlinks in the venv, which could point outside the venv

Comment: Thanks yes `PYTHONPATH` was the issue, found it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/5lIcq8P2REE